# How to add publication in academicpages.github.io?

Tags: jekyll

I forked https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io and I am trying to adjust the content. I want to add a publication on the publication site. So, I created "2021-05-21-willingness-to-vaccinate-against-COVID-19.md" in the publications folder.However, it does not show up on https://dangraeber.github.io. How does it come? My repo: https://github.com/dangraeber/dangraeber.github.io.

And does there exist a documentation for this template?

Thanks in advance!

Best

Daniel

Comment: if possible deploy locally in your system and let us know if any error throws up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I do a local build I'm getting the following error:

```
Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Markdown encountered an error while converting '_publications/2021-05-21-willingness-to-vaccinate-against-COVID-19.md':
                    The source text contains invalid characters for the used encoding UTF-8
```

It's the ö character in Schröder. If I remove that, I have no build errors.

You have three options I can think of:

1. Change ö the to o.
2. Use the HTML entry like so: `Schr&#246;der`.
3. Change your encoding. (I don't know enough about language encodings to give advice about this.)

Comment: i see these kinds of error often in jekyll, especially when in comes to languages other than english.